# Is it possible to get annotations of a method in advice related with field set pointcuts?

Tags: java, aspectj

I have an Aspect whose advice is executed when fields are set. I want to get annotation objects of methods where the advice executed (=where fields are set). Is it possible?

```java
public class WovenClass {

  private int value;

  @Validated({Group1.class, Group2.class})
  public void setField(int value) {
    this.value= value; // Advice should weave here and I want pass '@Validated' annotation to Advice.
  }
}

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  @AfterReturning("set(* *)")
  public void intercept(JoinPoint jp) {
    // I want to handle '@Validated' annotation here. 
  }
}
```

And also want to know if the pointcut expression for all field set is correct or not. Sorry for the multiple questions.

Comment: When posting code, please be careful not to post uncompilable pseudo code. For example, your `WovenClass` is missing the `class` keyword and the `void` keyword for the setter method. The pointcut in the aspect annotation is not enclosed in double quotes. Please give your questions some more love in the future and make sure your problems are reproducible. Be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for my mess, I fixed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Validation based on setter methods

Currently, you are intercepting field write access using a `set` poitcut. If you want to access annotations from setter methods, you need to use a pointcut which intercepts methods, such as `execution` and/or `@annotation`. Then it is easy to access the annotation.

The field write access `this.value= value` itself is not annotated and cannot be, because the JVM does not know annotations on individual lines of code. You could of course annotated the field and then fetch the annotation from the field, but I think the annotated setter method is a good way to do it. With the little bit of information you provided, this is hard to tell.

BTW, the `set` pointcut would also intercept field write access from places other than annotated methods, which does not seem to be what you want.

Another problem in your code is that in an `@AfterReturning` advice, you cannot   stop the value to be validated to be assigned, because, as the pointcut name implies, the aspect fires *after* the methods has already finished its job. You should either use a `@Before` pointcut, if you want to throw a validation exception in case of negative validation, or an `@Around` pointcut if you want to do something more sophisticated, such as setting a default value in case of negative validation. I am showing you the simple case in my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Helper classes to make the example code compile:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Group1 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Group2 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Validated {
  Class<?>[] value();
}
```

**Target class with setter to be validated and main method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class WovenClass {
  private int value;
  private String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Validated({ Group1.class, Group2.class })
  public void setField(int value) {
    this.value= value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should not be intercepted (no validation annotation)
    new WovenClass().setName("foo");
    // Should yield positive validation
    new WovenClass().setField(11);
    // Should yield negative validation -> exception
    new WovenClass().setField(0);
  }
}
```

**Validation aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.Validated;

@Aspect
public class ValidationAspect {
  @Before("execution(* set*(*)) && @annotation(validated) && args(value)")
  public void validate(JoinPoint jp, Object value, Validated validated) {
    System.out.println(jp);
    System.out.println("  validation rule: " + validated);
    System.out.println("  value to be set: " + value);
    // Some random condition in order to mimic a negative validation
    if (value.equals(0))
      throw new RuntimeException("field validation failed");
  }
}
```

Please note the consituents of the pointcut and how the annotation and the method parameter are both conveniently bound to advice method values, which you can directly access without any reflection magic for annotation access or ugly calls like `jp.getArgs[0]`.

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setField(int))
  validation rule: @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  value to be set: 11
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setField(int))
  validation rule: @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  value to be set: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: field validation failed
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.ValidationAspect.validate(ValidationAspect.aj:18)
    at de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setField(WovenClass.java:13)
    at de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.main(WovenClass.java:22)
```

### Validation based on field write access

**Update:** OK, now that we have established that for whatever reason you want to intercept field setters everywhere rather than only in annotated setter methods, using an `EnclosingStaticPart` advice parameter in order to get the calling method? But because chances are that some methods are not annotated with `@Validated` - e.g. `setName` in my example above - the advice gets triggered anyway. You have to search for the annotation via reflection and only perform validation when it is found.

I also extended the aspect to also cover validation annotations on constructors and adjusted the main class in order to test that:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class WovenClass {
  private int value;
  private String name;

  public WovenClass() {
  }

  @Validated({ Group1.class, Group2.class })
  public WovenClass(int value, String name) {
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Validated({ Group1.class, Group2.class })
  public void setField(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should not be intercepted (no validation annotation)
    new WovenClass().setName("foo");
    // Should yield positive validation
    new WovenClass().setField(11);
    // Should yield positive validation
    new WovenClass(22, "bar");
    // Should yield negative validation -> exception
    try {
      new WovenClass(0, "zot");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      System.out.println("  " + e);
    }
    // Should yield negative validation -> exception
    try {
      new WovenClass().setField(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      System.out.println("  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Executable;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.ConstructorSignature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

import de.scrum_master.app.Validated;

@Aspect
public class ValidationAspect {
  @Before("set(* *) && args(value)")
  public void validateFieldSet(JoinPoint jp, EnclosingStaticPart enclosing, Object value) {
    System.out.println(jp);
    Signature signature = enclosing.getSignature();
    boolean isMethod = signature instanceof MethodSignature;
    System.out.println("  Enclosing " + (isMethod ? "method: " : "constructor: ") + enclosing);

    Executable executable = isMethod
      ? ((MethodSignature) signature).getMethod()
      : ((ConstructorSignature) signature).getConstructor();
    Validated[] validatedAnnotations = executable.getDeclaredAnnotationsByType(Validated.class);
    if (validatedAnnotations.length == 0)
      System.out.println("  @Validated not found, skipping validation");

    for (Validated validated : validatedAnnotations) {
      System.out.println("  Validation rule:  " + validated);
      System.out.println("  Value to be set:  " + value);
      // Some random condition in order to mimic a negative validation
      if (value.equals(0))
        throw new RuntimeException("field validation failed");
    }
  }
}
```

The console log will change to:

```
set(String de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.name)
  Enclosing method: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setName(String))
  @Validated not found, skipping validation
set(int de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.value)
  Enclosing method: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setField(int))
  Validation rule:  @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  Value to be set:  11
set(int de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.value)
  Enclosing constructor: execution(de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass(int, String))
  Validation rule:  @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  Value to be set:  22
set(String de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.name)
  Enclosing constructor: execution(de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass(int, String))
  Validation rule:  @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  Value to be set:  bar
set(int de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.value)
  Enclosing constructor: execution(de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass(int, String))
  Validation rule:  @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  Value to be set:  0
  java.lang.RuntimeException: field validation failed
set(int de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.value)
  Enclosing method: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.WovenClass.setField(int))
  Validation rule:  @de.scrum_master.app.Validated(value={de.scrum_master.app.Group1.class, de.scrum_master.app.Group2.class})
  Value to be set:  0
  java.lang.RuntimeException: field validation failed
```

##### Resources for `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` and `EnclosingStaticPart`

> How could I know existence of EnclosingStaticPart arg? I think I searched into AspectJ references kind of deeply though. It would be nice if you could provide me a reference or something about it.

- The programming guide for native AspectJ syntax mentions the `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` variable in several places:

  - https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/printable.html#language-thisJoinPoint
  - https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/printable.html#quick-advice
  - https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/printable.html#reflective-access-to-the-join-point
- The developer's notebook for the annotation-based AspectJ syntax (more relevant for you) mentions `JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart`:

  - https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/printable.html#d0e3697
  - https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/printable.html#advice
- The [Javadoc mentions it](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart.html), but does not explain anything (sorry!). So that is not a very good reference. But at least it exists.
- If you are OK to buy a book, "AspectJ in Action, 2nd edition" by Ramnivas Laddad also mentions it in two or three places.

Comment: Thanks for providing sample codes and detail explanation!

`BTW, the set pointcut would also intercept field write access from places other than annotated methods, which does not seem to be what you want.`

Yes I know and it's what I want. I want aspects to intercept every field write access.
Besides, I want them to handle annotations only if the methods or constructors where aspects intercepted are annotated by `@Validated`.

Comment: And I don't need method args in this case. I'm trying to validate all fields of the object whose setter is written (=when aspects intercept), including cross parameter validation. 
Also I considered using `setter` methods and `execution` pointcut instead of `set` pointcut but what I want to do is annotate not only setter but any methods with `@Valdiated` so it didn't work for me.

Comment: **Update:** See my updated answer for an alternative solution using a field write access `set` pointcut according to your wish. It uses `EnclosingStaticPart` in order to find the surrounding method and from there the annotations on that method. Is this what you want?

Comment: **Update 2:** I just extended the aspect in order to also cover field write access from `@Validated` constructors. The aspect also logs more detailed information now.

Comment: It's a perfect solution for me!!!!!! thank you!!
How could I know existence of `EnclosingStaticPart` arg? I think I searched into AspectJ references kind of deeply though.
It would be nice if you could provide me a reference or something about it.

Comment: I updated the answer with a few links and pointers.

Comment: I'll check them! I really appreciate your dedication.